# Can LaunchConfiguration and cfn-hup play together?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have question regards to AWS CloudFormation - 
I have a stack that works in production, there are some services like WordPress, tomcat, etc. I have implemented cfn-hup script for updating stack and it works like a charm but I have a problem with commands which are defined in config-sets. all of these commands are running each time when the update process is working. It is problematic because very often I have "test" for commands and that tests are failed because eg. file has already existed because it was created during install command. so basically my question is - how to deal with the situation when we create and update stack? Do we need to use another configsets?

Answer (score 0):

You can use very useful [update-stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/update-stack.html) command.

[Medium](https://medium.com/boltops/a-simple-introduction-to-cloudformation-part-3-updating-a-stack-6fe2bb3931a9) link shows example how single instance template has been updated.

Comment: I have configured codepipeline (Codedeploy, codebuild) for updating my stack when I push some commits. It is configured full CI/CD. I don't use any CLI commands

Answer (score 0):

We usually try to make our commands idempotent in nature. In this way, even if the commands are run more than once there would be no issue. For your example, you could check for existence of the file before creating it. See below example:

```
[ -e "file_path" ] && $command
```

I am not really sure if all the config inside the configset mentioned in cfn-auto-reloader.conf are loaded or not. Let me know if you find more about this.